# Sort NSArray Using (Multiple?) Criteria -- Ages less than 10 ordered wrong

Tags: iphone, ios, nsarray, sorting

I need to sort an array of age groups. The challenge is that any age groups less than 10 sort higher than those 10-19 when using the standard NSArray `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare`

Specifically, here's an example of what my unsorted array might look like:

(
    "17-18",
    "13-14",
    "8 and Under",
    "Women",
    "Men",
    "15-16"
)

After sorting, I would *want* it to look like this:

(
    "8 and Under",
    "13-14",
    "15-16",
    "17-18",
    "Men",
    "Women"
)

But it ends up looking something like this:

(
    "13-14",
    "15-16",
    "17-18",
    "8 and Under",
    "Men",
    "Women"
)

This is using the following code:

```
    NSArray *sortedAgeArray = [ageArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

I like that "Men" and "Women" gets put on the end, that's what I want. But is there a clever/efficient way to deal with the ages that are less than 10? Reformatting my data to include leading zeroes is not an option.

I know I can write a custom sorting function, but I'm trying to avoid having to do so.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `localizedStandardCompare:` instead of `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:`. This is what the Finder uses and it's smart enough to evaluate "8" as smaller than "13" without leading zeros.

Comment: Woohoo! Worked perfectly. Thanks omz.

Comment: FWIW, you very rarely want to use a case-insensitive compare unless you are comparing for **equality**. If you want `a < B < c < D`, a plain `-localizedCompare:` will work fine (and `-compare:` might work too, depending on whether it uses the usual Unicode sort keys or something else).

Answer (score 0):

You either need to add leading zeros or write a custom function.

Or you can add an entire "sort key" to the front, separated by a character such as ":".  Eg, "17:17-18", "08:8 and under", "W:Women", etc.  Then use, eg, NSString::componentsSeparatedByString to split off the sort key before using the rest of the string in a presentation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Daniel. I was suspecting I would have to do something like this in the end, but omz's solution saved me the trouble. Appreciate your reply, though.